# MySQL: Generate a summary column without collapsing any rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a SQL table like this:

```
UniqueID  Word
1         apple
2         orange
3         banana
4         apple
```

I want to create a hash key as an integer. That integer should map to a particular word. So that the key has some meaning, I'd like the number to be the UniqueID of the first occurance of word. Which means I'd like to generate a table like this:

```
Unique ID  Word    WordHash
1          apple   1
2          orange  2
3          banana  3
4          apple   1
```

I tried using a group by statement, along with min(unique id), but that gets rid of the last apple row. I'd like to keep that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.UniqueID, t.Word, q.MinID AS WordHash
    FROM YourTable t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Word, MIN(UniqueID) AS MinID
                        FROM YourTable
                        GROUP BY Word) q
            ON t.Word = q.Word
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems the most straightfoward way. But the added inner join seems to slow the query down considerably (when compared to having no join and the group by word on the outer (only) select statement. MySQL can do the group by word efficiently on the outer select statement. So I was hopeful that there would be a way to keep  this speed and still have all rows returned. Maybe not...

Comment: Do you have an index on the Word column? That should make it more efficient.

Comment: Reading about MySQL indexing now. Looks promising. Will try this out tomorrow.

Comment: @Barmar Indexing the word column did the trick. That made the search go from NRows*NWords to NRows*C, where C<<NWords

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the new column in the original table in instead of just getting a result set:

```
update 
    t 
    inner join (
        select Word, min(UniqueID) as id
        from t
        group by Word
    ) s on t.Word = s.Word    
set t.WordHash = s.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute following queries

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD COLUMN `WordHash` INT NULL AFTER `Word`;

UPDATE <table_name> t INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT `word`, MIN(uniqueId) AS MinID FROM <table_name> GROUP BY `word`) q 
     ON t.word = q.word 
     SET WordHash = q.MinID;
```

Hope it helps...